# Automatic displacement in the column

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div>Text 1</div>
    <div>Text 2</div>
    <div>Text 3</div>
    <div>Text 4</div>
    <div>Text 5</div>
    <div>Text 6</div>
</div>
```

I have 6 elements in a single parent, if I can help with css turn them into 3 columns? That is, when the height of the child elements reaches a height of parent they shift to the right?
Now it looks like:

```
Text1
Text2
Text3
Text4
Text5
Text6
```

I want it to look like this:

```
Text1 Text3 Text5
Text2 Text4 Text6
```

Sorry for my bad english. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use css-columns to achieve it, but be carefull:

1. css-columns are not working for IE9 or older
2. columns do automaticly share the content evenly between the columns, so it depends on the content-length of the single divs how the content is distributed.

http://jsfiddle.net/tgv2rx7f/120/

```
.parent {
-webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
-webkit-column-gap: 30px; /* Defines the space between the columns for Chrome, Safari, Opera */
-moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
-moz-column-gap: 30px; /* Defines the space between the columns for Firefox */
column-count: 3;
column-gap: 30px;
}
```